# how to create a new theme for SugarCRM 6.1.0

Tags: php, sugarcrm

I want to create a new theme Sugar CRM 6.1.0.

I have copied the default theme but resources like js,css still coming from default theme.

I have changed the default theme in config.php.

Comment: so what is the question?

Comment: Also turn on developer mode in admin so you don't have cache turned on

Answer (score 2):

the easiest thing is to use one of the Sugar themes and modify this to your needs.

- Copy /themes/sugar/* to /custom/themes/myTheme/
- Modify themedef.php file to your needs:

  ```
  $themedef = array(
  'name' => "MySugar", // theme name
  'description' => "Sugar theme for me", // optional, short description of the theme
  'parentTheme' => "Sugar", // name of the theme this theme inherits from, in this case the Sugar theme
  );
  ```

  parentTheme is optional, and if not supplied, Sugar's default theme is used.
- All resources in /custom/themes/myTheme will override the parentTheme.

For more info see: http://developers.sugarcrm.com/docs/OS/6.1/-docs-Developer_Guides-Sugar_Developer_Guide_6.1.0-Chapter%204%20Customizing%20Sugar.html#9000992

Answer (score 1):

You don't need to copy an entire theme over, just extend the theme and add in the bits and pieces you need. So instead of above, do this:

- Copy /themes/sugar/* to /custom/themes/myTheme/
- Modify themedef.php file as follows

  ```
  $themedef = array(
     'name' => "MySugar", // theme name
     'description' => "Sugar theme for me", // optional, short description of the theme
     'parentTheme' => "Sugar", // name of the theme this theme inherits from, in this case the Sugar theme
     );
  ```

All resources that you add in the /custom/themes/myTheme directory will override the parentTheme.